# jQuery Remove All Elements from Select with Value

Tags: jquery

I have simple select that looks like this:

```
<select id="region">
  <option value=""> -- country -- </option> 
  <option value="842554592">Alberta</option> 
  <option value="708812360">Ontario</option>
  ...
</select>
```

I want to clear non-blank values and am wondering if jQuery has a simple method for this. I'm using:

```
$('.country').find('option[value!=""]').remove();
```

Which seems a bit ugly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to clear non-blank values and am wondering if jQuery has a simple method for this.

I don't think it is a common enough requirement to expect jQuery to have something like that out of the box.

You could write your own selector if you wanted...

```
$.expr[':'].nonEmptyValue = function(obj){
   return $(obj).val() != '';
};

$('#region option:nonEmptyValue').remove();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nGeFW/).

If you don't want the custom selector, you could also pass that function to [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) (replace `obj` with `this`).

Also, if you wanted to count whitespace only values as *empty*, do a `$.trim()` first on the value returned.